# How to implement Abstract class in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5.3

I was following Laracasts Api course and at a point i'm getting this error

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
ReflectionException in Container.php line 809:
Class App\Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer does not exist
```

i created a abstract class in app\Acme\Transformers\Transformer.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Acme\Transformers;

abstract class Transformer {

    //transformCollection the lessons data and return only requried fields
    public function transformCollection($items) {

        return array_map([$this, 'transform'], $items);

    }


    //transform the lessons data and return only requried fields of perticular id
    public abstract function transform($item);

}
```

and app\Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer.php

```
<? php 

namespace App\Acme\Transformers;

class LessonTransformer extends Transformer {

    public function transform($lesson) {

        return [
            'title'  => $lesson['title'],
            'body'   => $lesson['body'],
            'active' => (boolean) $lesson['completed']
        ];

    }

}
```

And My controller is LessonsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\lesson;
use Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer;

class LessonsController extends Controller {

    protected $lessonTransformer;

    function __construct(LessonTransformer $lessonTransformer) {

        $this->lessonTransformer = $lessonTransformer;

    }

    //fetch all and pass a metadata 'data' 
    public function index() {

        $lessons = Lesson::all();

        return Response::json([

            'data' => $this->lessonTransformer->transform($lessons)

        ], 200);
    }


    //fetch by id
    public function show($id) {

        $lesson = Lesson::find($id);

        if(! $lesson) {

            return Response::json([
                'error' => [
                    'message' => 'No Response Please Try Again'
                ]
            ], 404);
        }

        return Response::json([

            'data' => $this->lessonTransformer->transform($lesson)

        ], 200);
    }

}
```

I don't know what i'm missing
looking forward for much needed help

Thank You

Comment: I don't know if it's just a typo, but `<? php` needs to be `<?php` ;)

Comment: thanks for your time, my bad, it was a typo i fixed it and i.m getting a new error "ErrorException in Collection.php line 1321:
Undefined index: title "

Comment: in your index() method you need to call `transformCollection` instead of `transform` ;)

Comment: if i call transformCollection i'm getting this error FatalErrorException in Transformer.php line 10:
Call to undefined function App\Acme\Transformers\toArray()

Comment: Try `$this->lessonTransformer->transformCollection($lessons->all())` ?

Comment: ErrorException in LessonsController.php line 27:
Use of undefined constant ‌​ - assumed '‌​'

Comment: Don't know, but you should do some debugging of your own to get the rest to work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see by the error message, the problem is not related to the Abstract class Transformer, it was not able to reach that class yet because it was not able to find the LessonTransformer class?

```
Class App\Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer does not exist
```

Looking at your classes looks like all namespaces are good and, if you are using PSR4, **there's no need** to execute composer dumpautoload, it find it automatically.

But your class is not found and usually this happens because:

1) The file is misplaced (is it in the correct dir?).

2) The file is not correctly named.

3) You have an error in the file and PHP was not able to understand it as a class.

Comment: thanks for your time, it was a typo i fixed it and i.m getting a new error "ErrorException in Collection.php line 1321: Undefined index: title "

Comment: As I said, number 3, you had an error in the PHP file. Looks your collection doesnt have a title attribute. You better `dd($lesson)` to see what you have.